# Performing a one-liner on multiple input files specified by extension

Tags: perl

I'm using the following line to split and process a tab-delimited .txt file:

```
perl -lane 'next unless $. >30; @array = split /[:,\/]+/, $F[2]; print if $array[1]/$array[2] >0.5 && $array[4] >2' input.txt > output.txt
```

Is there a way to alter this one-liner in order to perform this on multiple input files without specifying each individually?

Ideally this would be accomplished by performing it on all files within the current directory holding the .txt (or other) file extension - and then outputting a set of modified files names e.g.:

**Input:**

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
```

**Output:**

```
test1MOD.txt
test2MOD.txt
```

I know that I can access the filename to modify it with `$ARGV` but I do not know how to go about getting it to run on multiple files.

**Solution**:

```
perl -i.MOD -lane 'next unless $. >30; @array = split /[:,\/]+/, $F[2]; print if $array[1]/$array[2] >0.5 && $array[4] >2; close ARGV if eof;' *.txt
```

`$.` needs to be reset otherwise it throws a division by zero error.

Comment: The problem is - `<>` is treated as a single filehandle. It's create if you want to cycle through the whole lot as a single stream, but it doesn't differentiate between files on the input.

Comment: @Sobrique So `<*.txt>` will batch process all lines simultaneously and lose input file information?

Comment: No. `while ( <> )` which `perl -n` supplies will though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind slightly different output file name,

```
perl -i.MOD -lane'
  next unless $. >30;
  @array = split /[:,\/]+/, $F[2];
  print if $array[1]/$array[2] >0.5 && $array[4] >2;
  close ARGV if eof;  # Reset $. for each file.
' *.txt
```

Comment: This produces an error of `Illegal division by zero at -e line 1, <> line 37864.` but I am not sure why - the line works on all individual files without error. Is this method skipping the first 30 lines for all input files or only for the first input file?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann this is all your code from above, you should probably catch exception with `eval {}` or test `$array[2] != 0` prior to division.

Comment: I did try `next if $array[2] = 0` to skip the line but it still returns a similar error. If the code runs on each individual file, could it be this kind of issue and not an issue with trying to use multiple files?

Comment: @AnnaSchumann `=` is assignment operator, and `==` is for comparing equality of numeric values.

Comment: I did also try that - the code now runs without error but completes instantly - returning nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered calling the perl script from a shell `for` loop?

```
for TXT in *.txt; do
   OUT=$(basename $TXT .txt)MOD.txt
   perl ... $TXT > $OUT
done
```